# how can i change .css or addClass of a textbox in a juery change function - help

Tags: jquery, css

I have a change functions as below:
All i want is whan a user clicks the button and the value is less than zero change the backgoundcolor of the textbox and viceversa if its greater that.
But it doesn't seem to work any ideas?

```
 $("input[name$=Text1]").change(function () {
     var value = $(this).val();
      $("p#pcms").text(value);

       var PerMonth = value-Pmmc;
        $("input[name$='spmtext']").val(PerMonth);

        if (PerMonth <0){
        $("input[name$='spmtext']").css("background-color","#FFFF00");
        }

         if (PerMonth >0){
        $("input[name$='spmtext']").css("background-color","#004080");
        }


}).change();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Brian said, you've got a couple issues here. I personally wouldn't hard code the selector on all of the CSS lines either. Since what you're referencing there is the selector, you can just use $(this), which will make your code a lot cleaner.

ie:

```
if (PerMonth <0){
  $(this).css("background-color","#FFFF00");
}
```

Comment: Thats of the the this now i know how to pay better with the selectors.
About if i want to show images instead of a backgound color?

Comment: You'd use the same method, just different CSS. For example,

$(this).css("background", "#00ff00 url('smiley.gif') no-repeat fixed center;");

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things wrong with your script,

1. you're binding to the change event for the selector. not the click event for a button, maybe your question is phrased.
2. where are you defining the variable reference for Pmmc ?

Also, im not sure what the secondary purpose of calling the change() at the end is for.

Comment: Thanks Brian
Quite new to Jquery but will catch up soon.
The code did eventually work but i has to check the initial value of the text box before i actually change the color.
The scenario is quite complicated as i have different webparts that loads on the page and when it load the css apply on the fly.
So all i did what check for the value of the textbox before i applied the CSS.
N